# javascript countdown timer, interval speeds up after click event

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, clearinterval

I started building a countdown timer. Thus far it is mostly working as I want. A button will either start or pause the timer. However if I start and pause it more than once, the interval will no longer remain set to 1000ms. This makes me think that it is now running multiple intervals in parallel per button click. I'm not sure how exactly to fix this or where exactly the problem is.

```
function startCountDown() {
  running = !running;
  running ? startButton.value = "Stop Countdown" : startButton.value = "Start Countdown";

  let t = timeDisplay.innerHTML.replace(/:/g, '');
  let seconds = t.slice(-2)
  let minutes = t.slice(-4, -2);
  let hours = t.slice(-6, -4);

  seconds > 60 ? seconds = 59 : seconds;
  minutes > 60 ? minutes = 59 : minutes;

  secondsRemaining = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + (seconds * 1)

  intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000)
  if (running === false) {
    clearInterval(intervalHandle)
  }
}

function tick() {
  if (running) {
    secondsRemaining--;
    console.log(secondsRemaining)
    hour = Math.floor(secondsRemaining / 3600)
    min = Math.floor((secondsRemaining - (hour * 3600)) / 60);
    sec = Math.floor((secondsRemaining - (hour * 3600) - (min * 60) ));

    timeDisplay.innerHTML = `${hour}:${min}:${sec}`
    if (secondsRemaining === 0 || running === false) {
      clearInterval(intervalHandle)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lines

```
intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000)
if (running === false) {
  clearInterval(intervalHandle)
}
```

you start a new timer everytime `startCountDown` is called. So, if there was a running timer before, you loose its ID, because the new timer's ID is stored in `intervalHandle`. Then, if `running` flag is `false`, you just stop the newly created timer, the previous one keeps running forever.

In other words, you leak a timer with every second call to `startCountDown`.

You should rewrite the code to something like

```
if (running === false) {
  clearInterval(intervalHandle);
} else {
  intervalHandle = setInterval(tick, 1000);
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!